# Is it possible to change frame of view controller in UITabBarController so that UITabBarController view will be visible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have my own subclass of UITabBarViewController. 
Is it possible to change frame for all embedded viewcontrollers' views so that own UITabBarViewController view will be visible partially?

On the attached image I set purple color for own tabBarController view.
I want to change frame of each selected view controller so that this purple view (UITabBarController view) will be visible.
[image]

Comment: did you get the answer for this qn? if so pls share the ans...Thanks in adv

Comment: I'm looking forward the answer too

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this answer looking for a solution myself, and found an okayish way to handle this: wrap your viewController inside another viewController as a childViewController.

Essentially, you would present a viewController with clear background, which has your content controller as childController with a frame you want it to have:

```
UIViewController *wrapperController = [UIViewController new];
wrapperController.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[wrapperController addChildViewController:vc];
[wrapperController.view addSubview:vc.view];
vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(...);
```

Just make sure to pass the tabbarItem to the wrapper, and use that one instead of the child.